# deletekeywords in Listings package sometimes doesn't work

Tags: pdftex, listings

Using the listings package, I can use `deletekeywords` to remove keywords, and so the keyword is not rendered in bold. For example, the `for` from the following is not in bold font:

```
\lstset{language=[]C++}
\begin{lstlisting}[deletekeywords={for}]
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {}
\end{lstlisting}
```

This is useful as I like to use the same font for small code snippets within the main body of my text, but don't always want it to appear with keywords in bold. I came up with two commands for convenience:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[deletekeywords=#1]{#1}}
\newcommand{\codeb}[1]{\lstinline[morekeywords=#1]{#1}}
```

However, with Fortran it doesn't work. The `do` in the following is still in bold.

```
\lstset{language=[]Fortran}
\begin{lstlisting}[deletekeywords={do}]
do i = 1,8
end do
\end{lstlisting}
```

Is there a way to do this? To locally override the keyword/language highlighting settings more generally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyword "DO" is defined as uppercase in `lstlang1.sty` and the code for Fortran says `sensitive=f`; so

```
deletekeywords={DO}
```

does the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why none of the following work: `deletekeywords={\uppercase{do}}` or `deletekeywords={\MakeUppercase{do}}` or `deletekeywords={\MakeTextUppercase{do}}`.

Comment: Anyway, I noticed that `keywordstyle=` is also very useful: `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[keywordstyle=]{#1}}
\newcommand{\codeb}[1]{\lstinline[morekeywords=#1]{#1}}`

Comment: `\uppercase{do}` can't work: it transforms "do" into "DO" only at processing time of the string and the string isn't processed at that time. Actually it's more complex than this, *marginis exiguitas non caperet*. :) Or *commenti exiguitas non caperet*, more properly.